# How to view/edit system and application files on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, filesystems

I'd like to explore the system files of some apps I've installed, but the program files aren't accessible when you plug in Windows Phone 8 via USB. I only see music, videos, ringtones, that kind of stuff.

Is there a way to view and edit the contents of the program files?

Comment: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3127